# $(scripttag).html() = undefined + Handlebars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

What am I missing?  How is it that works [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/YgfZx/), but what I have below is throwing undefined.  I have even tried downgrading my javascript and using the unminified version of handlebars.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/libraries/js/minified/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>
<script src="/libraries/js/minified/handlebars-1.3.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" />

<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="quagmire">giggity</div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var source = $("#entry-template").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var result = template();
</script>
```

The result I expect to get is an alert that says:

```
<div class="quagmire">giggity</div>
```

Comment: What is the *exact* error message? My first hunch would be that one or more of the scripts fails to load (i.e. $ is undefined or Handlebars is undefined).

Comment: `<script>` elements aren't allowed to self-close. The 2nd should have a `</script>`.

Comment: wrap your javascript in `$(document).ready(function(){ var source = $("#entry-template").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var result = template();});`

Comment: Jonathan, you should make that the answer because it is spot on.  Thank You!

Comment: The fiddle is not working on IE.